# Error in MeteorJS using D3

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Getting Exception in code regarding map data

**Error**

Exception in queued task: TypeError: data.map is not a function

```
var drawCircles = function (update) {
    var data = parseInt(CarBeands.findOne().percent);
    console.log(data);
    **console.log(pie(data));**
    var circles = svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc").append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill",function (d) {return color(d.data); });
    console.log(pie(data));
};
```

**Method**

```
CarBeands.find().observe({  
    added: function () {  
        x = CarBeands.find().fetch();  
        x.forEach(function(perce){  
            var san = parseInt(perce.percent);  
            console.log(san);  
            count += 1;  
        })  
        drawCircles(true);  
    }
});
```

In this code pie(data) showing that same **ERROR**

```
DataBase using MongoDB
{
    "percent" : "65",
},
{
    "percent" : "65",
},
{
    "percent" : "65",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is a single value here: you fetch one element and get it's value with `.percent`.

`map` applies to an array.

`d3js` usually expects an array of values as input.

`data.map()` is not a function because `data` is not an array

To get the array, you need to use

```
var data = MyCollection.find().fetch().map(function (item) {return item.percent})
```

That will get you an array of the percent numbers.